# Are references with indication of page number uncommon in computer science?

Tags: citations, writing, computer-science

I am writing a computer science paper in which I cite several lengthy sources (text books and standard specifications). Whenever I cite such a source, I add the page numbers of the subsection to which I refer, e.g.:

> Bla bla is considered very important [52, pp. 210-214].

One of the reviewers of the paper remarks the following:

> Do not use references with indication of page numbers (e.g., [52, pp. 210-214]), this is very uncommon.

*Is this really true (in computer science)?*

*Am I wrong to include the page numbers in the reference?*

The reference in question is a 400+ page book that broadly covers a whole subject area and I thought knowing which pages I actually refer to might help the reader. There are several other (and longer) sources, such as technical standards, which I cite in the same fashion.

Comment: I can't address how common citing page numbers in books is in computer science, but it certainly ought to be standard.  I'd recommend ignoring the reviewer's comment.

Comment: Yes, it's uncommon; no, you're not wrong to do it.

Comment: It seems like a practical issue as well: Many CS textbooks that _I've_ read were digital copies with no page numbers at all!

Comment: This is uncommon for a reason. You should not reference by page number unless there is really no better way to reference the part you need (which means that the book is badly organized). The book might grow by a couple pages in a new edition and your page-number references are screwed.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Based on the answers, I'm not sure this question is particularly asking for *page numbers* as such, rather than for *any kind of further specification* where to find the particular cited statement in the referenced work.

Comment: @darijgrinberg - So long as you're careful to cite the edition in your references, that shouldn't be a problem. If the author says "pp 210-214" in the citation, and the reference says "3rd edition," then I can figure out that all bets may be off for page numbers in later editions. Plus, the page numbers may still be helpful; if I have the fifth edition on my bookshelf, I might still be able to find the relevant passage if I can just get a table of contents for the earier edition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many computer science venues are fairly picky about their citation styles and also use highly abbreviated citation styles that don't give any option for including additional information like a page number.

If page numbers are critical to your citation, then you have two options for how to include them while conforming to the required style:

1. If you only use one narrow set of pages in the book, use an "in-book" style citation (@inbook in BibTeX) that includes the page numbers in the reference.
2. Alternately, or if you refer to more than one set of pages, you can include the pages in the text rather than the citation:

> Bla bla is considered very important, as described on page 210--214 of [52].

Comment: ACM, for example, does not include page numbers in the in-text reference [style](http://www.acm.org/publications/submissions/latex_style).

Comment: Thanks @jakebeal and @bill-barth! This seems to be a good solution for my problem. Interestingly, [the IEEE style guide](http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf) uses the "in-book" style, but also [52, pp. 210-214] (see page 7).

Comment: @joergl That passage in page 7 of the style guide refers to "references within a reference", which is probably not your case.

Comment: @federico-poloni: Are you sure? The IEEE style guide talks about "ibid. or op. cit.". As far as I understand, this refers to, e.g., different sections in the same book.

Comment: The best way to conform to computer science citation styles is to use the LaTeX packages supplied by pretty much every venue (including IEEE and ACM) as their preferred format.

Comment: @joergl No, I am not sure. :) That point seems very unclear in the guide.

Comment: -1, bad advice. [Do not use @inbook](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2515/how-to-cite-chapter-in-book/2568#2568). Do not use numeric citations as part of a sentence ("page 210-214 of [52]"); they are similar to footnotes.

Comment: @JukkaSuomela I've happily used inbook for a long time.  Perhaps you can provide a reason that it should not be used, beyond the [ad populum fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum) in the linked post?

Comment: "The best way to conform to computer science citation styles is to use the LaTeX packages" - when relying on that rule, contrary to what @BillBarth suggested, all three LaTeX packages from the linked ACM site happily display page numbers in the in-text reference style, when citing in the `\cite[page]{source}` style.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Awesome.  Then I would totally trust ACM's machine-interpretable de facto standard over their human-readable and ambiguous documentation.

Answer (score 13):

Specifying which part of a long book or article you are referring to in your citation is a sound practice, but in general section, theorem or equation numbers are more common than page numbers for this task: [52, Section 3.5] or [52, Equation 3.23] rather than [52, Page 132-134].

Personally I use page numbers only as a last resource where nothing else is available: that is, when the section or equation I want to refer to does not have a number of its own.

I do not have a compelling reason for this, if not that section numbers are more robust to minor pagination changes, but this is the behaviour that I have seen more commonly.

Comment: Thanks, I aggree that section numbers or equations are more stable than page numbers. I think I will combine your solution with jakebeal's, e.g. "...as described in Sect. 3.1 of [52]."

Comment: Why are section numbers more stable than page numbers? For a formally published work (i.e., not on ArXiv), neither should ever change, except by the publication of a new edition of a book. But, in new editions, it's very common for section and theorem numbers to change, too.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Based on the current practice, I agree. However, I also firmly believe in the principle of separation of content and presentation, and with that in mind, I do perceive the current notion of a "formally published work" as being a document nailed down to one particular layout as a relic from pre-digital times. Ideally, a "formally published work" is the published text in its published, logical structure, along with its internal references and attachments (images, tables, ...). Such data can be represented in any layout, and page numbers are indeed unreliable there.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The logical structure isn't as fixed as you seem to be assuming. Some formats for mathematics number the theorems, lemmas etc. in the same sequence (e.g., Lemma 1, Lemma 2, Theorem 3); some in their own sequences (e.g., Lemma 1, Lemma 2, Theorem 1); some include the section number (e.g., Lemma 1.1). So, just as reformatting can break page numbers, it can also break more "structural" references.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: True, that numbering needs to follow a deterministic algorithm, of course. If it does, though, it is more meaningful than page numbers, that have next to no inherent relationship to the content.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: in a preprint, the pages are numbered 1, 2, 3, ... but in the published paper they are numbered in sequence with all the other papers, so the pages might be 140, 141, 142, ...  The section numbers will be the same, however. So in fields where preprints are common, citing sections or theorem numbers has practical advantages.

Comment: @OswaldVeblen Sure but in a preprint on ArXiv, the theorem numbers might be different from the version published in the journal.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I am not claiming that this works universally and with formal guarantees, but there are many real-world cases where section numbers are indeed more stable than page numbers. For instance, different reprints of a book differing only by misprint corrections, or faithful translations in another language. Also, many journal allow for the publication on arXiv of a [postprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postprint), that is, a paper in its final post-refereeing state. A postprint has the exact same content of the final paper, but different style and pagination.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: They could be in principle, but the page numbers are essentially *guaranteed* to be different, while the section numbers are relatively likely to be the same, in my experience. Things would be different in fields where they don't release preprints.

Comment: Just to be clear, I am not saying "you should cite section numbers from an arxiv version without checking that the ones on the published version are the same"; I am saying "you should cite section numbers from the published version, not page numbers, so that in 99% of the cases a reader without access to the published version can use the arxiv one".